# using davfs without root, problem with groups

Tags: permissions, fstab, davfs2

```
bruni@PROX15:~$ mount /home/bruni/Documents/Data_Buero/Egroupware/wd_files
/sbin/mount.davfs: user bruni must be member of group davfs2
bruni@PROX15:~$ groups bruni
bruni : bruni dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio video plugdev users input lpadmin davfs2
bruni@PROX15:~$
```

Could somebody enlighten me with regard to the error message *user bruni must be member of group davfs2*? As I understand it, bruni already is a member of davfs2.

Comment: Did you only *recently* add the user to the group? the change doesn't take effect until the next login session

Comment: have you tried closing, opening terminal or even reboot?

Comment: @steeldriver thank you....that was once again too simple...Just put it in an answer, restart solved the problem